# How to build dynamic lib for iOS with XCode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, makefile, xcode4.3, dylib

I am trying to build a dynamic library for iOS 5, but there is no template for this. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 5):

There are no user dynamic library for iOS, at least none that are officially supported. Indeed, an iOS app (which Apple would accept in its App Store) must me comprised of a single binary file (plus resources). This means that you can only link static libraries with your main program.

> The iOS SDK supports the creation of native applications that appear on the device’s Home screen only. It does not support the creation of other types of code, such as drivers, frameworks, or dynamic libraries. If you want to integrate code from a framework or dynamic library into your application, you should link that code statically into your application’s executable file when building your project.

([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/IPhoneOSOverview/IPhoneOSOverview.html) - "What can you create?" section)

Of course, dynamic linking is supported by iOS; it is only that Apple does not support its use in iOS apps, except for SDK frameworks.

If you are interested in creating a dynamic library anyhow, have a look at [this article](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20110712175443515&mode=print). The trick is starting with a plain Cocoa (i.e., MacOS) framework bundle, then change the build settings in order to compile against the iOS SDK.